# Magento 2 : Rearrange Block Argument Items Using ReferenceBlock

Tags: magento2, layout, blocks

I'm using `magento 2.4` and trying to customize the items ordered table in admin order detail page via `MyVendor\MyModule\view\adminhtml\layout\sales_order_view.xml`. Here, if I reference the block to add an item everything works, but if I change the order of the items, then the `referenceBlock` doesn't work anymore and I have to reset the whole block.

Original xml:

```
<block class="Magento\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Order\View\Items" name="order_items" template="Magento_Sales::order/view/items.phtml">
 <arguments>
  <argument name="columns" xsi:type="array">
   <item name="product" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Product</item>
   <item name="status" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Item Status</item>
   <item name="price-original" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Original Price</item>
   [other items]
 </arguments>
 [child blocks]
</block>
```

My custom layout to add a new item to original arguments:

```
<referenceBlock name="order_items">
 <arguments>
  <argument name="columns" xsi:type="array">
   <item name="product" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Product</item>
   <item name="status" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Item Status</item>
   <item name="price-original" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Original Price</item>
   <item name="my-column" xsi:type="string" translate="true">My Column</item>
   [other items]
 </arguments>
</referenceBlock>
```

This work: the `referenceBlock` takes the block and adds my-column to the table.

My custom layout to re-arrange existing items using referenceBlock:

```
<referenceBlock name="order_items">
 <arguments>
  <argument name="columns" xsi:type="array">
   <item name="status" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Item Status</item>
   <item name="product" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Product</item>
   <item name="price-original" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Original Price</item>
   [other items]
 </arguments>
</referenceBlock>
```

Here I didn't add any new column, I simply changed position to the "status" column so it shows before the "product" column. In this case, `referenceBlock` doesn't work.

My custom layout to re-arrange existing items resetting the block:

```
<block class="Magento\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Order\View\Items" name="order_items" template="Magento_Sales::order/view/items.phtml">
 <arguments>
  <argument name="columns" xsi:type="array">
   <item name="status" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Item Status</item>
   <item name="product" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Product</item>
   <item name="price-original" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Original Price</item>
   [other items]
 </arguments>
 [child blocks]
</block>
```

This works: I can see the status column displayed before the product column. Resetting the block, though, means that I have to re-write all the child blocks in my layout as well, and I'd like not to do it since I'm not modifying those.

So my question is: is there a way to use `referenceBlock` to only re-arrange the argument's items of the block?

Comment: I'm struggling with the same issue and seems like the answer is 'no'.

Comment: Look like you can create a plugin with a afterGetColums() method where you can add or move the array in any way you choose. See https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/334916/change-position-of-custom-column-in-order-view-item-table-magento-2